# XML Schema: multiple adjacent xs:documentation elements within xs:annotation

Tags: xsd

I am looking at an **XMLSchema *.xsd** file and see forms like the following:

```
     <xs:element name="shortName" type="vr:ShortName" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:annotation>
           <xs:documentation>
             blah blah blah ...
           </xs:documentation>
           <xs:documentation>
              blah blah blah ...
           </xs:documentation>
           <xs:documentation>
              blah blah blah ...
           </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
     </xs:element>
```

That is, adjacent **xs:documentation** elements within an **xs:annotation** element.

I don't know what kind of meaning I am supposed to ascribe to such a form or how is that different from a single **xs:documentation** element. Presumably a tool might render the different documentation elements as separate paragraphs but isn't that kind of mingling presentation logic with the logical structure discouraged?

Comment: From my experience, this is typically what you see when XSDs are automatically generated by a tool. A typical reason behind it is that the tool captures user information at different levels and for different reasons that happen to coalesce when generating a schema component and its annotation. It then makes sense, at least to a tool implementer, to maintain that separation of content using different markup. Another reason may be that same XSD is used to generate UI for different form factors, so then when annotations are used, different attributes associated `documentation` help distinguish...

Comment: (cont'd) which one to use. It is hard from your example (which seems to repeat the same text) to speculate what was the intention in what you saw... Now, it is also true that just because there are good reasons, it doesn't mean that they apply in your specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is valid to have multiple `xs:documentation` elements inside the same `xs:annotation`. It could make sense to use multiple elements when there is documentation in multiple languages:

```
 <xs:element name="shortName" type="vr:ShortName" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:annotation>
       <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
         This is the documentatin in English ...
       </xs:documentation>
       <xs:documentation xml:lang="it">
          Questa e' la documentazione in italiano ...
       </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
 </xs:element>
```

You could also see multiple `xs:documentation` element in XSDs generated automatically by a tool. A typical reason behind it is that the tool captures user information at different levels and for different reasons that happen to coalesce when generating a schema component and its annotation. It then makes sense, at least to a tool implementer, to maintain that separation of content using different markup.

Another reason may be that same XSD is used to generate UI for different form factors, so then when annotations are used, different attributes associated documentation help distinguish which one to use.

`xs:documentation` elements can contain arbitrary XML, not just text. These means that typically formatting for the documentation is rendered with some markup inside the `xs:documentation` nodes - e.g. using `<p>...</p>` to mark paragraphs.

[Answer updated / improved based on info provided by Petru Gardea in the comments]

Comment: @PetruGardea: I write '...some markup..' - seems pretty generic to me

Comment: @PetruGardea: why don't you write an answer here explaining these things - maybe with some examples? I'd be happy to upvote it